# Payment gateway receives api calls from different Azure ip's on "Standard-website"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are running a Medium Standard Website instance, and on this we have a few webshops, when the customer tries to capture funds(API call to payment gateway) it sometimes shifts ips, and we need to add the new ip(s) to the gateways approved ip range.

Any ideas why it shifts and is there a way to lock the ip?

We been using it these ips so far:

81.95.255.42

81.95.242.214

81.95.240.42

94.246.104.73

94.245.107.113

94.245.88.135

94.245.88.250

94.245.104.73

94.245.88.217

94.245.88.231

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow. You should post there, so that a proper answer can be posted. That said: Azure WebSites service doesn't offer reserved IP addresses. The service itself is multi-tenant, even though your site(s) use dedicated VMs.

Comment: Arh okay, didnt know serverfault existed, i will move the post and thx for an answer aswell.

Comment: Ive created it here http://serverfault.com/questions/632352/service-receives-api-calls-from-different-azure-ips-on-standard-website